# What is solidus and liquidus temperature of granite?

Tags: volcanology, mineralogy, petrology, magmatism, igneous

My understanding is that because a rock is composed of variety of minerals, so it does not have fix melting point, rather there is a range below which whole rock is solid and above which whole rock is liquid. I want to know this liquidus and solidus temperature for granite rock based on pressure (as we can't ignore role of pressure inside earth where granite is formed?

Comment: Water content is probably the most important thing you need to know in addition to pressure to be able to answer that correctly.